# Join request in jpa entities

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a API with hibernate jpa and spring, and I want to do a join with jpa entity manager, and i keep having this error :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: game_id of: jack.persistence.models.Progress [from jack.persistence.models.Game g, jack.persistence.models.Progress p where g.id = p.game_id and p.user_id = 2]
```

Here is the request :

```
public List findAllAndProgress() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from Game g, Progress p where g.id = p.game_id and p.user_id = 2")
            .getResultList();
}
```

The fields of Game entity :

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "genre")
private String genre;

@Column(name = "year")
private String year;
```

The fields of Progress entity :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "game_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private Game game;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Task.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List taskList;

private double completion;
```

Finally In the database, here are the fields of the table Game and Progress that hibernate create :

```
Game (id, genre, title, year)
Progress (id, completion, game_id, user_id)
```

Comment: try this `Select g from Game g, Progress p where g.id = p.game.id and p.user.id = 2`

Comment: You either need `g = p.game` or `g.id = p.game.id` At the moment you are referencing a property `p.game_id` that doesn't exist in your Progress class. Hibernate naming conventions relies on the class names, not the database column names

Comment: Wow thank you ! "p.game.id" worked for me

Comment: This is a nasty solution since it could be done more properly. Also had no time to give at least an explenation but I'm really busy atm. If anybody wants the 15 RP pls do...

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621856/hibernate-hql-help-querying-foreign-key/9622204)